# How to create a project using yo office that enabled SSO for React

Tags: reactjs, single-sign-on, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I want to create an Excel office add-in using yo office generator that allows me to pre-configure SSO features for react

I follow few steps and created addin project using

`yo office`

[image]

I referred official documents from Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/sso-quickstart)

The library will generate full-source code in JavaScript or TypeScript. Is it possible to use it in a React project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the required for react UI dependencies using the `npm install` command. The office-generator provides a skeleton for the react-enabled add-in without SSO, so you may try to generate one to observe what dependencies are required for that and then combine everything into a single add-in project. See [Use Fluent UI React in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/using-office-ui-fabric-react) for more information.

Comment: Yes, that I understood, but how do I combine sso with react framework?

Comment: You need to install the required node packages and update the webpack.config.js file.

Comment: Ok let me do it

Comment: I have generated SSO and React projects using `yo office` and in react project I have moved all SSO logic and its dependencies. finally this solution are worked

Comment: That is also a possible way to go! Glad it worked for you.

Comment: The solution was helped me. Thanks, Eugene for your help.

Comment: hi Kishan. Do you have a sample of the integrated SSO + react solution? I can't seem to make it work the same way you did (it always wants MSAL auth, and the redirect uri is not working well). Thanks!